Relationship Between the Polarization Density and the Electric Field for a Dispersive Medium
The relationship between the polarization density $\mathbf{P}$ and the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ for a dispersive medium is given in many sources as
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{P}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}\epsilon_0\chi(t - t')\mathbf{E}(t')dt' = \epsilon_0\chi(t) *\mathbf{E}(t)
\end{equation}
What is the origin of the formula? Would someone be able to point me in the direction of/provide a derivation of this? I understand that in the dispersive case we can't simply have $\mathbf{P}(t) = \epsilon_0\chi(t)\mathbf{E}(t)$ because the molecules won't be able to instantly respond to a quickly changing field. I'm just confused how that delay manifests mathematically as the above convolution integral.

This is a Linear response function formula. The electric field causes the polarization density to appears. The polarization on time $t$ not only depends on the field in this time, but in all the others previous times.
You asked for some kind of derivation so here it is. Consider that the electrons are in the material with specific equilibrium positions. For simplicity, let's assume one dimensional material. For a given electron, say that it has a quadratic potential $V= {1\over 2} k(x-x_0)^2$ near the equilibrium position $x_0$. If we denote $s = x(t)-x_0(t)$, the equation of motion under an applied external electrical field will be
$$
m_e {d^2s\over dt^2} = eE(t) - ks\\
{d^2s\over dt^2} +\omega_0^2 s =\frac em E(t)
$$
One way to solve this equation is by Fourier transform. If we do it, we get
$$
(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)S(\omega)=\frac em E(\omega)
$$
We define the response function
$$
\xi (\omega) = {S(\omega)\over E(\omega) }= \frac em {1\over \omega^2-\omega_0^2}
$$
Now, applying the Fourier transform back, by convolution theorem, we would have
$$
s(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\xi(\omega)E(\omega)) = \int \xi(t-t')E(t') dt'
$$
Usually, the displacement of the equilibrium position induces a dipole moment $d=es(t)$, since the electrons usually are bounded to positive nucleus. The polarization density then is defined as $P = N d$, where $N$ is the number of electrons per unit of volume in the material. We have
$$
P(t) = N e s(t) = \int Ne \xi (t-t')E(t')dt' \equiv \int \epsilon_0 \chi(t-t')E(t')dt'
$$

The validity of linear response functions go beyond my heuristic demonstration. Look that for this model, we would have
$$
\chi(\omega) = {Ne^2\over m\epsilon_0} {1\over \omega^2-\omega_0^2}
$$
Which has one singularity, but we could include some damping in electron displacement to avoid it.

Thank you so much, this was extremely helpful and exactly what I was looking for.

Starting from the fact that $\vec P$ is a functional $\vec P[\vec E]$, three assumptions are made:

Causality: $\vec P(t)$ depends on $\vec E(t’)$ only when $t’<t$,

Linearity: the expression that you give is not exact but only a first-order expansion in $\vec E$. We get
$$\vec P(t)=\vec P(0)+\int_{-\infty}^t \chi(t,t’)\vec E(t’)dt’$$
where
$$\chi(t,t’)=\left.{\delta P(t)\over\delta E(t’)}\right|_{E=0}$$

Time translation invariance :
$$\chi(t,t’)=\chi(t-t’)$$
which permits to put the integral under the form that you give.



Thank you for providing this! Listing the assumptions cleared some things up.
